# Is there a way to sync music on my iphone?

Tags: sync, iphone, itunes

I been trying to use Banshee to sync my Iphone 4 but it doesn't appear to work is there any other way to sync music to my iphone ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about Iphones, but on my Android I use Dropbox to sync music and documents between my phone and computer automatically
I would be surprised if dropbox is not available for apple